# Shell script fails to create a mysql backup

Tags: command-line, bash, mysql

I want to create a shell script to automatically backup MySQL DB. I will later copy it to an s3 bucket.

I have created the following shell script:

```
#vim /home/ubuntu/backup/mysqlbackup.sh

#!/bin/bash
## Specify the name of the database that you want to backupbackup

# Database credentials
USER="user1"
PASSWORD="password"
HOST="hostname.compute.amazonaws.com"
DB_NAME="db1"

#Backup_Directory_Locations
BACKUPROOT="/home/ubuntu/backup"
TSTAMP=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
S3BUCKET="s3://s3bucket"
#LOG_FILE="/home/ubuntu/backup/log/dump.log"

mysqldump  -h <HOST>  -u <USER>  --database <DB_NAME>  -p"$PASSWORD" > $BACKUPROOT/$DB_NAME-$TSTAMP.sql
```

Then from the command line, I run the script:

```
sudo bash -x ./mysqlbackup.sh
```

And it fails, telling me:

> HOST: No such file or directory

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`<HOST>`. `<DB_NAME>` etc, are just placeholders.

They should be replaced by actual strings or shell variable expansions `"$HOST"`, `"$DB_NAME"` and so on - just as you have done with `-p"$PASSWORD"`

The error message is because `<` and `>` are redirection operators.